# Why doesn't mutate function generate variable?

Tags: r

the code is the following:

```
tb   <- tibble(
               year   = rep(2001:2020,10)
)

tb %>% arrange(year) %>%
    mutate(
           id   =  rep(1:10,20),
           r1   = rnorm(200,0,1),
           r2   = rnorm(200,1,1),
           r3   =  rnorm(200,2,1)
    )

for (i in 1:5) {
      tb %>% mutate(
        T_i = r1*(year = 2004 + i) + 
              r2*(year = 2007 + i) +
              r3*(year = 2009 + i)
                   )
}

colnames(tb)
```

I hope to see  6 variables after `colnames(tb)`: `"year" "id" "r1" "r2" "r3" "T_i"` but it seems the `for` loop doesn't work. So I can only get the first five variables while `T_i` does not show up. I don't know why.

Comment: Because you need to assign `tb <- tb %>% ..` to change the object.  Otherwise, it just prints on the console

Comment: Do you want only 1 column `T_i` ? Or you want 5 columns `T_1`, `T_2`, `T_3`, `T_4` and `T_5` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the pipe (`%>%`) operator, you haven't yet assigned `tb` to its new value. You are currently simply printing what `tb` would look like after applying the pipe.

The correct edit would be:

```
tb   <- tibble(year   = rep(2001:2020,10))

tb <- tb %>% arrange(year) %>%
    mutate(id   =  rep(1:10,20),
           r1   = rnorm(200,0,1),
           r2   = rnorm(200,1,1),
           r3   =  rnorm(200,2,1))

for (i in 1:5) {
      tb <- tb %>% mutate(
        T_i = r1*(year = 2004 + i) + 
              r2*(year = 2007 + i) +
              r3*(year = 2009 + i))
}

colnames(tb)
```

In general, the following simply prints:

```
dat %>% mutate(...)
```

The following assigns a new value to the variable:

```
dat <- dat %>% mutate(...)
```

And you need to do both together if you wish to reassign the value and print:

```
dat %>% mutate(...)
dat
```

If you want to do both in one line, also try:

```
(dat %>% mutate(...))
```

Comment: Or, if `library(magrittr)` is fully loaded (not just the dplyr `%>%` alias), one can do `dat %<>% mutate(...)` for assignment, and `dat %<>% mutate(...) %T>% print()` for print and assign. See [magrittr docs](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html).